# Live view focus problem with Nikon D600 and 50/1.8G

Tags: nikon, 50mm, nikon-d600

I just bought a new D600 and a Nikon AF-S 50/1.8G lens. However, it fails to focus in live view mode. It just searches without success. Live view focus works fine with my Tamron 28-300 Zoom and my Nikon 16mm fisheye.

How can the choice of lens affect the ability to focus? Should I start troubleshooting the camera body or the lens?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you focus the 50mm when not in live view?

Comment: Yes. In the viewfinder everything works fine!

Comment: did you try to focus with higher f-number f/10 or more in Live view?

Comment: Also were you focusing in the same conditions as with your other lenses? Live view AF works via edge contrast detection, so it needs decent light and a relatively well contrasted subject.

Answer (score 1):

I went back to the dealer and got a new camera body. Now it works fine! What a strange error...